# Error after adding new item UserControl Form in VS c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

I have a project in c# Windows Form Application where I am trying to add a UserControl. But whenever I add the UserControl from the Form, the page shows an error message. I checked the `Designer.cs` file, there are two red marks. One at `Dispose` and another at `AutoscaleMode`. In the form, when I Click `Show Call Stack` I get the following error:

> 1. Hide Call Stack at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.CodeModel.CSharpCodeModelService.GetTypeSymbolFromFullName(String fullName, Compilation compilation)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.RootCodeModel.DotNetNameFromLanguageSpecific(String languageName)
>      at EnvDTE80.CodeModel2.DotNetNameFromLanguageSpecific(String LanguageName)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.CodeTypeDeclarationFromCodeClass(CodeClass vsClass)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnNamespacePopulateTypes(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>      at System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace.get_Types()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.MergedCodeDomParser.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeParser.Parse(TextReader stream)
>      at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

Please can anyone solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friends. I named the folder 'UserControl'. It was the main reason for this error. After renaming the folder the issue was resolved. When I thought of checking Error List I saw in form.cs that

But I want keep this post to tell people never use Keywords such as "Form", "UserControl", etc as directory or folder name. They will mess-up.

Thank to stackoverlow for providing such a great platform.